# Combining jQuery Ajax Code Not Working

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I am trying to amalgamate two ajax functions that use jQuery. Both work perfectly on their own, but I'm having a hell of a time combining the two, and I'm pretty green when it comes to Ajax. I can't figure out what's wrong.

I know this is asking a lot of someone, but I don't know what else to do. I would be extremely grateful for any help, and perhaps an explanation of what I would need to do if I wanted to add more functionality to this code so I don't have to keep bothering you all.

It's an image gallery. The two halves are a combo box to select how many images show per page, and the other is pagination to navigate the pages. I have a feeling it has something to do with the jQuery Ajax `data: {page:page, imgs: value}` but that might just be part of the problem.

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="loading"></div>
<div id="gallery_container">
    <ul class="new_arrivals_gallery"></ul>
    <div class="pagination"></div>
    <form>
        <label>Images Number:</label>
        <select id="imgNum" name="imgNum">
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>      
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

**The JavaScript (jQuery):**

```
function loading_show(){
    $('#loading').html("<img src='loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
}
function loading_hide(){
    $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
}                
function gallery_show(){
    $('#gallery_container').fadeIn('slow');
}
function gallery_hide(){
    $('#gallery_container').fadeOut(10);
}

function loadData(page){
    loading_show();
    gallery_hide();                    
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "GET",
        url: "new_arrivals_data.php",
        data: {page:page, imgs: value},
        success: function(msg)
        {
            $("#gallery_container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
            {
                gallery_show();
                loading_hide();
                $("#gallery_container").html(msg);
            });
        }
    });
}
loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
$('#gallery_container .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
    var page = $(this).attr('p');
    loadData(page);
});           
$('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
    var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
    var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
    if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
        loadData(page);
    }else{
        alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
        $('.goto').val("").focus();
        return false;
    }
});

//Bind the onChange event to Fetch images on combox selection
$("#imgNum").change(function(){
    //The combo box
    var sel = $(this);
    //Selected value
    var value = sel.val();
    loadData(page);
})
//You should store the current selected option in a cookie
//For the sake of the example i'll set the default permanently to 12
var imgNum_selected = 12;

//set the initial selected option and trigger the event
$("#imgNum [value='"+imgNum_selected+"']")
    .prop("selected","selected")
    .change();
```

**The PHP:**

```
<?php
if($_GET['page'])
{
$page = 0;
 if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page = (int) $_GET['page'];
 }
$cur_page = $page;
$page -= 1;
if((int) $_GET['imgs'] > 0){ 
    $per_page = (int) $_GET['imgs']; 
} else { 
    $per_page = 12; 
}
$previous_btn = true;
$next_btn = true;
$first_btn = true;
$last_btn = true;
$start = $page * $per_page;

include"db.php";

$query_pag_data = "SELECT `imgURL`,`imgTitle` FROM `images` ".
"ORDER BY `imgDate` DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page";

$result_pag_data = mysql_query($query_pag_data) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());

echo "<ul class='new_arrivals_gallery'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_pag_data)) { 
    echo "<li><a href='new_arrivals_img/".$row['imgURL']."' class='gallery' title='".$row['imgTitle']."'><img src='new_arrivals_img/thumbnails/".$row['imgURL']."'></a></li>";
  }
echo "</ul>";   


/* --------------------------------------------- */
$query_pag_num = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM images";
$result_pag_num = mysql_query($query_pag_num);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_num);
$count = $row['count'];
$no_of_paginations = ceil($count / $per_page);

/* ---------------Calculating the starting and endign values for the loop----------------------------------- */
if ($cur_page >= 7) {
    $start_loop = $cur_page - 3;
    if ($no_of_paginations > $cur_page + 3)
        $end_loop = $cur_page + 3;
    else if ($cur_page <= $no_of_paginations && $cur_page > $no_of_paginations - 6) {
        $start_loop = $no_of_paginations - 6;
        $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
    } else {
        $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
    }
} else {
    $start_loop = 1;
    if ($no_of_paginations > 7)
        $end_loop = 7;
    else
        $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
}
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
$msg .= "<div class='pagination'><ul>";

// FOR ENABLING THE FIRST BUTTON
if ($first_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
    $msg .= "<li p='1' class='active'>First</li>";
} else if ($first_btn) {
    $msg .= "<li p='1' class='inactive'>First</li>";
}

// FOR ENABLING THE PREVIOUS BUTTON
if ($previous_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
    $pre = $cur_page - 1;
    $msg .= "<li p='$pre' class='active'>Previous</li>";
} else if ($previous_btn) {
    $msg .= "<li class='inactive'>Previous</li>";
}
for ($i = $start_loop; $i <= $end_loop; $i++) {

    if ($cur_page == $i)
        $msg .= "<li p='$i' style='color:#fff;background-color:#006699;' class='active'>{$i}</li>";
    else
        $msg .= "<li p='$i' class='active'>{$i}</li>";
}

// TO ENABLE THE NEXT BUTTON
if ($next_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
    $nex = $cur_page + 1;
    $msg .= "<li p='$nex' class='active'>Next</li>";
} else if ($next_btn) {
    $msg .= "<li class='inactive'>Next</li>";
}

// TO ENABLE THE END BUTTON
if ($last_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
    $msg .= "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='active'>Last</li>";
} else if ($last_btn) {
    $msg .= "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='inactive'>Last</li>";
}
$goto = "<input type='text' class='goto' size='1' style='margin-top:-1px;margin-left:60px;'/><input type='button' id='go_btn' class='go_button' value='Go'/>";
$total_string = "<span class='total' a='$no_of_paginations'>Page <b>" . $cur_page . "</b> of <b>$no_of_paginations</b></span>";
$msg = $msg . "</ul>" . $goto . $total_string . "</div>";  // Content for pagination
echo $msg;
}
```

Thank you so much to whomever takes the time to look at this. I know it's a lot, but even if someone tells me what needs to be done, and then I figure out how to do it, I would be extremely grateful.

*I would be willing to include the code of each part before I tried to combine them, if that would help.

---

***ORIGINAL SEPERATE CODE:***
Here are both sets of the original code. The goal is to combine them, in other words add code #2 to code #1.

**HTML & jQuery #1:**

```
<body>
    <div id="loading"></div>
    <div id="gallery_container">
        <ul class="new_arrivals_gallery"></ul>
        <div class="pagination"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            function loading_show(){
                $('#loading').html("<img src='loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
            }
            function loading_hide(){
                $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
            }                
            function gallery_show(){
                $('#gallery_container').fadeIn('slow');
            }
            function gallery_hide(){
                $('#gallery_container').fadeOut(10);
            }

            function loadData(page){
                loading_show();
                gallery_hide();                    
                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "new_arrivals_data.php",
                    data: "page="+page,
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        $("#gallery_container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                        {
                            gallery_show();
                            loading_hide();
                            $("#gallery_container").html(msg);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
            $('#gallery_container .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
                var page = $(this).attr('p');
                loadData(page);

            });           
            $('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
                var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
                var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
                if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
                    loadData(page);
                }else{
                    alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
                    $('.goto').val("").focus();
                    return false;
                }

            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

**PHP #1:**

```
<?php
if($_GET['page'])
{
$page = $_GET['page'];
$cur_page = $page;
$page -= 1;
$per_page = 15;
$previous_btn = true;
$next_btn = true;
$first_btn = true;
$last_btn = true;
$start = $page * $per_page;
include"db.php";


$query_pag_data = "SELECT `imgURL`,`imgTitle` FROM `images` ".
"ORDER BY `imgDate` DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page";

$result_pag_data = mysql_query($query_pag_data) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());

echo "<ul class='new_arrivals_gallery'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_pag_data)) { 
    echo "<li><a href='new_arrivals_img/".$row['imgURL']."' class='gallery' title='".$row['imgTitle']."'><img src='new_arrivals_img/thumbnails/".$row['imgURL']."'></a></li>";
  }
echo "</ul>";   


/* --------------------------------------------- */
$query_pag_num = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM images";
$result_pag_num = mysql_query($query_pag_num);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_num);
$count = $row['count'];
$no_of_paginations = ceil($count / $per_page);

/* ---------------Calculating the starting and endign values for the loop----------------------------------- */
if ($cur_page >= 7) {
    $start_loop = $cur_page - 3;
    if ($no_of_paginations > $cur_page + 3)
        $end_loop = $cur_page + 3;
    else if ($cur_page <= $no_of_paginations && $cur_page > $no_of_paginations - 6) {
        $start_loop = $no_of_paginations - 6;
        $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
    } else {
        $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
    }
} else {
    $start_loop = 1;
    if ($no_of_paginations > 7)
        $end_loop = 7;
    else
        $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
}
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
$msg .= "<div class='pagination'><ul>";

// FOR ENABLING THE FIRST BUTTON
if ($first_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
    $msg .= "<li p='1' class='active'>First</li>";
} else if ($first_btn) {
    $msg .= "<li p='1' class='inactive'>First</li>";
}

// FOR ENABLING THE PREVIOUS BUTTON
if ($previous_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
    $pre = $cur_page - 1;
    $msg .= "<li p='$pre' class='active'>Previous</li>";
} else if ($previous_btn) {
    $msg .= "<li class='inactive'>Previous</li>";
}
for ($i = $start_loop; $i <= $end_loop; $i++) {

    if ($cur_page == $i)
        $msg .= "<li p='$i' style='color:#fff;background-color:#006699;' class='active'>{$i}</li>";
    else
        $msg .= "<li p='$i' class='active'>{$i}</li>";
}

// TO ENABLE THE NEXT BUTTON
if ($next_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
    $nex = $cur_page + 1;
    $msg .= "<li p='$nex' class='active'>Next</li>";
} else if ($next_btn) {
    $msg .= "<li class='inactive'>Next</li>";
}

// TO ENABLE THE END BUTTON
if ($last_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
    $msg .= "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='active'>Last</li>";
} else if ($last_btn) {
    $msg .= "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='inactive'>Last</li>";
}
$goto = "<input type='text' class='goto' size='1' style='margin-top:-1px;margin-left:60px;'/><input type='button' id='go_btn' class='go_button' value='Go'/>";
$total_string = "<span class='total' a='$no_of_paginations'>Page <b>" . $cur_page . "</b> of <b>$no_of_paginations</b></span>";
$msg = $msg . "</ul>" . $goto . $total_string . "</div>";  // Content for pagination
echo $msg;
}
```

**HTML & jQuery #2:**

```
<body>


<form>
    <label>Images Number:</label>
    <select id="imgNum" name="imgNum">
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>      
    </select>
</form>

<div id="imgTray"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script> 
<script>

//Bind the onChange event to Fetch images on combox selection
$("#imgNum").change(function(){
    //The combo box
    var sel = $(this);
    //Selected value
    var value = sel.val();

    //Feth the images
    $.get("get_images.php",{imgs: value}, function(data){
        //Add images to the document
        $("#imgTray").html(data);
    });
})

//You should store the current selected option in a cookie
//For the sake of the example i'll set the default permanently to 12
var imgNum_selected = 12;

//set the initial selected option and trigger the event
$("#imgNum [value='"+imgNum_selected+"']")
    .prop("selected","selected")
    .change();

</script>
</body>
```

**PHP #2:**

```
<?php
    if((int) $_GET['imgs'] > 0){ 
        $limit = (int) $_GET['imgs']; 
    } else { 
        $limit = 12; 
    }

     $curPage = 0;
     if(isset($_GET['page'])){
        $curPage = (int) $_GET['page'];
     }

    $mysql_link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");   
    mysql_select_db("new_arrivals_imgs") or die("Could not select database");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `imgURL`,`imgTitle` FROM `images` ".
    "ORDER BY `imgDate` DESC LIMIT " . $limit * $curPage . ", $limit") or die(mysql_error());

    if(!$query) {
        echo "Cannot retrieve information from database.";
    } else { 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
        echo "<li><a href='new_arrivals_img/".$row['imgURL']."' class='gallery' title='".$row['imgTitle']."'><img src='new_arrivals_img/thumbnails/".$row['imgURL']."'></a></li>";
      }
    }

?>
```

---

**Thought I should mention:** When I change the `data: {page:page, imgs: value}` back to what it was in code #1: `data: "page="+page` the images show, and the pagination works. Alas, the combo box is not visible. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Maybe it's just because it's late here in Germany that I don't understand your problem, but what exactyl is not working? HTML not showing up after the GET request is completed? Pagination not working? Which 2 functions are you talking about?

Comment: haha! even I dint figure out the prob.. well its close to midnight in India and may be I have special powers to see the prob.. :P

Comment: @Björn Kaiser Well at this point nothing is working. All that is showing up is the loading gif and the html combo box(which does nothing if I select a number). I will post the two original Ajax codes as well in a hope that this will help.

Comment: is page always set to some value? make sure there are no errors on the server side.. try debugging the server side code to see if you are getting a request and how you are handing it there

Comment: @zzzz Page is not always set to the same value. How would you suggest I debug the server side code? I know for a fact that both sets work perfectly, but I'm not sure if it is the combination of the PHP code that is the problem, or the combination of the jQuery.

Comment: i dnt know how does 1 debug php..i wrk on .net and its easy as eating a pie.. sorry! probably put in sm log statements to log it smwhere (console,database).. see if there is a log else your code is not being called.. put logs at beginning and end if it fails smwhere in middle.. make intelligent guesses..

Answer (score 1):

I dont think the following code:

```
$("#gallery_container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
            {
                gallery_show();
                loading_hide();
                $("#gallery_container").html(msg);
            });
```

should be in the success function of your ajax call..

The API states that

> Whenever an Ajax request completes, jQuery triggers the ajaxComplete event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the .ajaxComplete() method are executed at this time.

Thus in your case any further ajax requests should fire the ajaxComplete event and call the callback function for the same..

Hope that makes sense.. I have not worked with the ajaxComplete API myself and this is my understanding

Comment: Thanks. You're not the first person to tell me this. However, the original code contained this and it worked fine, so I'm not sure if that is the problem here. I posted both sets of original code in hopes that it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Your `success` callback be just this:

```
success: function(msg) {
    gallery_show();
    loading_hide();
    $("#gallery_container").html(msg);
}
```

That way, when you successfully get your HTML (in `msg`) back from the server, you will show the gallery, hide the loader animation, and stuff the `msg` HTML into the gallery.

The [`ajaxComplete` function](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete) registers an "AJAX is done" handler:

> Whenever an Ajax request completes, jQuery triggers the `ajaxComplete` event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the `.ajaxComplete()` method are executed at this time.

But you're not doing any AJAX on `#gallery_container`, you are doing things to it but it doesn't know that those things originate from AJAX actions. The result is that your success handler does nothing that the user can see.

An `error` handler might be a good addition as well, then you could move the "hide loader animation" to a `complete` handler:

```
success: function(msg) {
    gallery_show();
    $("#gallery_container").html(msg);
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Tell the human that something broke.
},
complete: function() {
    // This is always called regardless of success or failure.
    loading_hide();
}
```

The [`complete` handler](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is:

> A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed).

So that's a good place to put any cleanup that you always want to happen.

Comment: As usual, thank you. You're a god send. I've made the said changes, and added a `,` after the success function ;) But alas, it is still not working. The Loading gif spins and spins, there are no images, no combo box, and no pagination numbers. Any more ideas?

Comment: **Thought I should mention:** When I change the `data: {page:page, imgs: value}` back to what it was in code #1: `data: "page="+page` the images show, and the pagination works. Alas, the combo box is not visible. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @stefmikhail: Any server errors? Are you sure that your PHP is getting called? Does the error callback get triggered? Anything in the JavaScript console? Either version of `data` should be okay as long as the values are right.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the PHP is getting called, otherwise it wouldn't work when the data is set to `data: "page="+page` right? The error callback does not get triggered under either of the stated data calls. I'm mystified however as to why the combo box isn't even visible? It is for a second when the page loads, and then it's gone. You say either version of `data` should be ok. Why is that? What does `data` mean?

Comment: The `data` is passed to the `url`, if it is an object (i.e. `{page:page, imgs:value}` then it is converted a normal parameter string (i.e. `"page=" + page + "&imgs=" + value`). If `value` isn't defined then you could get a JavaScript error with the `{...}` version. Do you get any errors in your browser's JavaScript console?

Comment: @moo is too short: and what on earth does `"page="+page` mean anyway?

Comment: Yes I am getting an error: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: value`. I did notice that `var value` is defined below the ajax call. Could that have to do with it?

Comment: I've managed to stop the javascript error, but the combo box is still not visible. I have no idea why, but I'm wondering if it wouldn't be better to `echo` the entire combo box and form just like the pagination is from the php file?

Comment: `"page="+page` is string concatenation. Yes, the Reference error would be a problem and explain why one version of `data` works but the other doesn't; you probably want `loadData(page, value)`. Is there a live version of this anywhere?

Comment: @muistooshort let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2719/discussion-between-stefmikhail-and-mu-is-too-short)

Comment: I've moved this into a chat room if you're able to join. I don't have this live anywhere as I'm just building it on my MAMP localhost.